# New dataframe from a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
teste.head(5)

               card_id       feature_1       feature_2  
0      C_ID_92a2005557               5               2  
1      C_ID_3d0044924f               4               1
2      C_ID_d639edf6cd               2               2
3      C_ID_186d6a6901               4               3
4      C_ID_cdbd2c0db2               1               3
```

And I have this other dataframe:

```
historical.head(5)

    authorized_flag           card_id   city_id   category_1    installments    category_3  merchant_category_id        merchant_id
0                 Y   C_ID_cdbd2c0db2        88            N               0             A                    80    M_ID_e020e9b302
1                 Y   C_ID_92a2005557        88            N               0             A                   367    M_ID_86ec983688
2                 Y   C_ID_d639edf6cd        88            N               0             A                    80    M_ID_979ed661fc
3                 Y   C_ID_d639edf6cd        88            N               0             A                   560    M_ID_e6d5ae8ea6
4                 Y   C_ID_92a2005557        88            N               0             A                    80    M_ID_e020e9b302
```

Comments:
The first dataframe has only some information about the card_id and the value I want to predict (target)

The second dataframe looks like the history of each card_id containing the columns I need to merge to the first dataframe (giving more information / columns for each card_id)

obviously the card_id in the second dataframe is repeated several times, with this, from the second dataframe I need to create a new dataframe, not letting the card_id multiply.

I can use:

historical.groupby('card_id').size()

and create a new column with the number of times that cad_id was used.

But I'm not able to do this with the rest of the columns because I need to sum all the values ​​in each column and associate each card_id to then merge with the first dataframe

Can you help me create the new columns in the best way?

Comment: your merge strategy is a bit hard to follow- can you pick an id and show expected result? in particular, what do you do when id is repeated in second data frame?

Comment: for those other columns do you wanna aggregation like sum or mean or just simply keep any one of them?